# regex - optionally capture 2 groups

Tags: java, regex

I have a string containing eg. 1a2b. The number is 1 to 9 and the letter (a|b) is constant. I want a regex that looks for '1a' and '2b' where either group is optional.

I have this...

```
    String description = "bla bla bla: 1a2b more bla bla bla";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([1-9]a)([1-9]b)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(description);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(" group1: " + matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(" group2: " + matcher.group(2));
    } else {
        System.out.println("no match");
    }
```

which outputs

```
group1: 1a
group2: 2b
```

If I add `?` after EITHER group it still works. If I add `?` after BOTH it still matches but returns null for both groups.

How do I make both groups optional so that it will match

case 1: "bla 1a bla"

case 2: "bla 2b bla"

case 3: "bla 1a2b bla"
?

Comment: Just a quick question: why not use `([1-9]?)([ab])`? You say `a` and `b` are constant. So, only the digit can be absent.

Comment: One, the other or both: `([1-9]a)|([1-9]b)|([1-9]a)([1-9]b)`

Comment: You can use: `"([1-9]a)([1-9]b)?|([1-9]a)?([1-9]b)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible ways of doing that:

1. Having one group twice:

   If you use `"([1-9]a)([1-9]b)?|([1-9]b)"`, it will match what you want, but you will have to check both groups 2 and 3 to find the part with the `b`.
2. Using lookahead

   In the regex `"(?=[1-9][ab])([1-9]a)?([1-9]b)?"`, first a positive lookahead will ensure that one of the two following groups will match, then the two groups get their chance on the matching.

Solution 1 is more portable (not all regex engines support lookahead) and probably slightly faster (and easier to understand for most), but requires a change in using the groups (you have to check if group 2 (or group 1) is `null` and use group 3 in that case.

Comment: Thanks. 1. works for me. I'll accept this answer if no one else can provide an answer without the pipe.

Comment: @TedTrippin This is no pipe, it is a logical OR

Comment: Search for "vertical bar" on wikipedia.